# Find and replace in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse

Editing a C file in eclipse. I hit ctrl + f to search for a string in the file. A dialog box pops up and i type my search in there. Then I go back to editing the file. The next time I hit ctrl + f to do a different search, I lose focus on the editor window and i don't have focus in the search window. I have to actually click on the find and replace window to be able to type in what I want to search for now. If I close the find and replace window then ctrl + f works normally again, but I don't think that is really acceptable. Surely there is a way to navigate back to the find window without having to click on it?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem with Eclipse Oxygen.1a, but without success: after hitting Ctrl+F the focus was always in the _Find_ field of the _Find/Replace_ dialog. Which Eclipse version do you use? Where was the focus instead? Was the focus in the C editor before you pressed Ctrl+F (if the focus is in a view that does not support _Find_ Ctrl+F will be ignored)?

Comment: I see this problem - always, Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
Build id: 20171218-0600, Ubuntu. Was this fixed?